# Can we get a Twitter user's e-mail address using the Twitter API

Tags: twitter

If I have a user's Twitter ID or handle, can I get the e-mail address of this ID?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very confusing but here is the rule for receiving users' email.

- Your application must have been approved by Twitter. More details can be found at https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials > *Request a User’s Email Address*. When using the [form](https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform) you will have to pick *I need access to special permissions* and inform that you want your application to have access to the user's email.
- When you are approved you need to refresh all your application keys.
- When this is done you need all your users to re-authorize your app with the new keys.
- Finally when you call the `account/verify_credentials` endpoint you will receive the user's email.

Comment: Just one additional point, after calling `oauth/authorize`, you'll also need to call [`account/verify_credentials`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials) with the `?include_email=true` flag in order to retrieve the email address.

Comment: @Linvi, How can my application send for approval to twitter. It have any send request form or I send mail to them.

Comment: I have updated the answer to provide more accurate information.